# How to open new popup windows in my case?

Tags: javascript

I want to open a new window as a popup when user clicks a link and use it as the only popup window if user clicks the links again. I am not sure how to do it.

I have tried

```
window.open('test/'+id+'.html','','width=1017, height=689', true);
```

and tried adding different parameter in it but still not sure how to do this.

Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot

Comment: Put something besides an empty string in the second argument (name it something).

Comment: [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window name as @Dagg suggested.

```
window.open('/test1', 'window_name', true);
```

Then, if you want to open another url in the same popup:

```
window.open('/test2', 'window_name', true);
```